# Photoshop: Replace Color With Transparency

Tags: photoshop

I want to replace the black color in this image with transparency. This would also mean that the gradient in the center of the image would not fade to black but fade to transparency. How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: How is this question related to programming? I think this would be a better match for Superuser.com.

Comment: You should ask this question on [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is there a way to migrate question/answer threads between StackExchange sites? This would be a great way to manage threads like this which are helpful but simply asked on the wrong forum.

Comment: the answer is here... https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/2417/76368. Use Gimp's `Color to Alpha` feature. Amazingly there is no Photoshop equivalent, but it work's so well in Gimp and for results that good it is no sweat to switch between the two programs occasionally!

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/21704/45239 was helpful for me to remove unwanted white.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The general approach with a solid-color b/g:

1. Click on the background with Magic Wand: the area becomes surrounded by wavy dashes
2. Hit the Delete key: background has a hatched pattern
3. Save and Done

For this to work your image must be RGB. If it isn't already make an RGB copy. If there are different shades of black in the background, you have to do this for each group of pixels that have a different RGB definition. In other words, it's easy with a solid-color background and increasingly time intensive depending on the number of RGB combos in the graphic's background.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on all layers?

Comment: This doesn't seem like the answer to this particular question, which is not about replacing a solid color, but a gradient.

Comment: Didn't work for me/my PS version, even though I do have an RGB image. This YouTube video did explain a method that worked for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SV38L4c4JKY.

Comment: This answer does not address the question, since the image in question does not have a solid-color b/g. A better answer is provided here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21685/replacing-whiteness-with-transparency-in-photoshop. It is not perfect - the procedure still leaves a hint of the original background color in the transparency, but it does provide a transparency gradient, which is what the question asked for.